# convert rst files to pdf by latex,How can I change the fonts?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to change my pdf files fonts, I want to use source code pro fonts, how can I change? I use sphinx-doc to generate pdf files by latex.

Answer (score 1):

In your Sphinx configuration file, set the `fontpkg` of the [latex_elements](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html?highlight=fontpkg#confval-latex_elements) variable as follows:

```
latex_elements: {
   'fontpkg': '\\usepackage{sourcecodepro}'
}
```

Comment: Thank,And I don not know how to set font size about the first class subject and the second class subject and the text?? In my documention, I also want to make chinese font use Microsoft YaHei, the english font and Arabic numerals use Arial font?? Please look at the image and how can I set in conf.py??